# I want to start my new bitcoin web wallet! Coding and steps! PLEASE GUIDE

Tags: e-wallet, webapp

I want to start my new bitcoin web wallet but no idea where to start. coding and steps no idea. please help.

Comment: Hey, between you and me, if you don't know how to code a wallet, you probably shouldn't offer a service where you use said wallet to manage other people's money.

Comment: It will be my personal wallet. can you teach me how to code a wallet?

Comment: The question does not provide enough detail to answer it satisfactorily. OP hasn't specified any programming language, should there be a server, and so on. There are lots of implementation details in building a wallet, so much so, the actual mechanics of signing are only a small part of the project.. The question should request specific details, and not how to realize an unspec'd project.

Answer (score 1):

**As I said in the comment above, you're talking about a service to manage actual money. Please don't offer this service to other people until you're sure it's working properly and it doesn't have security flaws.**

You should try to make your wallet work with the **Bitcoin Testnet** first. The Testnet is a clone of the Bitcoin network that gets reset every once in a while. Therefore, its tokens are valueless. However, it allows you to experiment with your software and test functionality because it behaves like the Bitcoin network.

Now, depending on what your favorite programming language is, there are different [libraries](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software#Libraries) for Bitcoin already. If you're fine with Java, it is my understanding that [`bitcoinj`](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj) is rather comprehensive and well-kept. There are also some open-source Bitcoin wallets already that use `bitcoinj` which you might use to inspire yourself how to solve some issues. One such wallet is the [Bitcoin Wallet for Android](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj).

From there, I suggest that you apply standard software development techniques: Define use cases, structure work into manageable chunks, design a solution, define testcases, and implement functionality.